# Compound perspectives with CSS 3d transformations

Tags: css, 3d, css-transitions, css-transforms

I'm trying to build a simple game with 3d CSS whose structure resembles Stratego, or any other game with upright cards that get toppled:

[image]

Setting the perspective of the board is easy:

```
<div id="table">
  <div id="board"></div>
</div>
```

With CSS:

```
#table {
  perspective: 1000px; 
  perspective-origin: 50% 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}

#board {
  transform: rotateX(50deg);
  background-color: pink;
  width: 500px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

Easy enough:

[image]

Then I added a bunch of divs representing the pieces, using [this handy tutorial](http://davidwalsh.name/css-flip) as a guide. If you click one of the divs, it flips down.

But the blue-and-gray divs are stuck to the plane of the original rotation, it appears. The top never gets larger as the flip occurs. If I give them any sort of default rotation, they don't appear to come out of the plane and sit upright:

[image]

Here's the [live example](http://codepen.io/wilson428/pen/VYzByw).

I'm new to CSS 3D transforms, and I suspect this is a simple matter. Essentially what I want is cascading rotations, I think? Thanks much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Fiddle/](http://jsfiddle.net/poi33/v6pemrt4/1/)

**So basically what you needed was perspective in a perspective.**
It can be done but it does not give a realistic look.
What i have done in the fiddle above is:
**Set the child elements to be siblings instead**

```
<div class="board"></div>
<div class="card">
    <figure class="front"></figure>
    <figure class="back"></figure>
</div>
```

This was you can se your perspective to both of them separately.
To avoid setting double perspective you can simply add a parent div and set the perspective there since it will maintain perspective in child elements.

Comment: Brilliant! With some tinkering I made it feel more natural as well: http://jsfiddle.net/v6pemrt4/2/

Comment: I don't fully understand the translateZ, however

Comment: When I try to use z-values I think off  **a ball on a string**. If you rotate a ball without an string it will only rotate on its own axis. Attach a string and suddenly the ball will rotate around the end of the string not on its own axis.  That's basically what  the translateZ(-100px) does.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.card-container .card.flipped {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
  transform-origin:top
 }
```

I suggest to also try setting a border to the card as it might render better.

Comment: No luck, unfortunately. But whatever solution also needs to worth initially, when the card is "upright." The card needs to come out of the screen, so to speak.